# Is there an extensive guide on using the Notation Package?

Tags: packages

I've always wondered if there is any relatively comprehensive guide to using the `Notation` Package.

Can anyone give any recommendation on this?

I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: There was a nice [presentation](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=notation&c=104&v=3570) on `Notation` at WTC 2021.

Comment: Presentation [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/rohit.namjoshi/NotaionsAndObjects_WTC2021.nb).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion! :-)